# How do I calculate the correlation coefficient between these two sets of data, taking into account the uncertainty values I have for one of them?

Tags: correlation, regression-coefficients

I have two sets of data, both of which have a varying pattern pattern. I believe that one set of data (in blue in my image) illustrates the cause of the pattern which shows in the other set of data (in black/red in my image).

[image]

I would like to calculate the correlation coefficient between the two sets of data, but I'm not sure what I should use to calculate the coefficient. I was going to use Pearsons's correlation coefficient, but I realise that doesn't take into account the uncertainties I have in one of the data sets, and it also may not work as the behavior isn't linear?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Spearman rank correlation, which will assign ranks and make adjustments for ties in each variable, and will be less sensitive to the spiked values in the lower plot, and the singletons which are visible in the top plot.  Pearson correlation may be overly sensitive to the larger displacements caused by the observations in the peaks (bottom) and the outliers (top plot), and falsely return a greater (positive or negative) correlation coefficient along with significance.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I eventually just calculated spearman's and pearson's since it's pretty simple in Python. The coefficients were close enough to be identical for my purposes, and they don't appear to actually correlate.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that correlation will miss any nonlinear connection between the two variables.  Before addressing the uncertainty (is it measurement error?) of the G-R values, you could model the best estimates for them as a function of MJD, allowing for nonlinearity.  This could be done in a variety of ways, such as with regression splines, quadratic or cubic functions, or (in more exploratory fashion) loess or lowess curves.  You should crossvalidate to see how well any nonlinear relationship holds up.

Then, to deal with the uncertainty of G-R, you could impute values and then conduct a simulation.  Allowing G-R to take on any of the values within its  likely range for each value of MJD, you could treat that new, expanded set of G-R values as the dependent variable to be explained by MJD.  Again you could use any of the methods I mentioned for identifying the nature of any relationship.  The uncertainty will show up because now, for a given value of MJD, you will have additional variation in G-R.  Thus with imputation I expect you will obtain a weaker indication of the relationship, but maybe a more accurate set of coefficients or a more trustworthy standard error for each of them.